# How to make inter cloud foundry calls (from app running in one PCF environment to an app running in another PCF environment)

Tags: spring-boot, cloud, cloud-foundry, pcf

For a requirement, I have to make service call to an app running in PCF production environment from an app running on PCF non-production environment. All applications are developed using Spring boot. All kinds of solutions or patches are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to call the App's `Route` directly and access .. There is no `behind-the-loadbalancer` connection unless and untill you are in to the same space

Answer (score 2):

There really isn't anything Cloud Foundry specific in play here. At a high level, what you're going to do is the same as if you're accessing a service running on the same Cloud Foundry instance or even some random service running on the public Internet.

You're going to use Spring's RestTemplate to make a request to the service. The request you send will depend on the API of the service you're trying to consume. The request will go out to the service and you'll get a response. RestTemplate will help with parsing the response into a Java object and your app can go about consuming the response.

The trick to this will be network access. The consuming service will need to be able to send a request on the network and have that routed to the producing service. This may or may not be possible depending on how your company's network is set up. No one here can help you with that though. You need to talk to someone within your company, probably your Cloud Foundry operator or a network admin to confirm if that is allowed or possibly to add application security group rules or open up firewall ports.

Sorry I can't be more specific, but I hope that helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it is indeed an network issue. I will surely reach out to network admin team. I will post steps that were taken to make it work. Thank you.